# how to programmatically add allow rule to iis?

Tags: c#, iis-7, active-directory

I'd like to ask how to programmatically add allow rules to IIS.

In my sample, I will dynamically create a IIS virtual directory by "DirectoryEntry", and then I want to set the authorization to a sepecific user not all users. So, how should I do it using C#?

Comment: Put a little bit of effort into your own researching before asking questions.  Best place to start is google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I've finally taken is to make a web config template like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<security>
<authorization>
<remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
<add accessType="Allow" users="{0}" />
</authorization>
</security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then replace the users with the one I want to authorize, then write the web config file to the virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried googling for the answer?  A quick google and these are some of the links I found.  I know the first one is written in VB but you could easily conver it.

[MSDN Very Similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/6ae0449f-9b4a-4634-b54d-6bc19a3d3961/) 
[Blog describing how to create\delete and view virtual directories in C#](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/06/20/createdeleteview-virtual-directory-or-website-in-iis-using-c/)
[MSDN Managed Authorisation Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.server.managementauthorization%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)